# Firebase Crashlytics unique ID

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Is the `installation_uuid` field in the BigQuery table of my project's Crashlytics data the same thing as what is being set with [setUserIdentifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/CrashlyticsCore.html#setUserIdentifier(java.lang.String)), and comes back with [getIdentifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/CrashlyticsCore.html#getIdentifier())? If not, should we be able to read the `installation_uuid` in any way in our app code?

Comment: Did you took a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports) of Firebase Crashlytics?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks the installation UUID is different than your userID. It is used to track the number of unique users experiencing a crash. It is not developer accessible as that would allow you to link users and UUID and would create privacy concerns out of the box that we'd rather mitigate.